# Find repetitions in a list

Tags: list, prolog

How would I go about finding consecutive repetition of a string in a list in prolog.

What I'm exactly trying to find, for example, is this:

```
input => output
AAAAAA  =>  6*(A)
ABABAB  =>  3*(AB)
ABCABCABC  =>  3*(ABC)
```

I wrote a DCG grammar for this and I'm trying to have it give me this as a result.

Here's the grammar, if needed:

```
exp --> term.
exp --> term, [+], exp.

term --> factor.
term --> digit, [*], exp.

factor --> elem.
factor --> ['S'], ['['], sym, [']']. %S[(A)(B),(C)]
factor --> ['<'], alt, ['>'], ['/'], ['<'], alt, ['>']. %<(A)>/<(B)(C)(D)>
factor --> ['('], exp, [')'].

sym --> factor.
sym --> factor, [','], factor.
sym --> factor, sym.

alt --> factor.
alt --> factor, alt.

elem --> char.
elem --> char, elem.
char --> [D], {is_alnum(D)}.
digit --> [D], {is_alnum(D)}.
digit --> [D], {number(D)}.

nbr_to_char(N, Cs) :-
    name(Cs, [N]).
str_to_list(S, Cs) :-
    name(S, Xs),
    maplist(nbr_to_char, Xs, Cs).

eval(L) :-
    str_to_list(L, X),
exp(X, []).
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice to provide the grammar?

Comment: I didn't find it necessary, as the grammar handles way more cases than this one, but I'll put it anyway.

Comment: Why would `ABCABCAB` result in `3*(ABC)`? And what would you want `AAABBBAAABBB` to result in?

Comment: I'm trying to find the most factorized version by finding patterns like repetition. So this would result in 2*(AAABBB). Of course, the original pattern isn't known ('AAABBB', in this case).

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I forgot a 'C'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is pack([dcg_util](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=dcg_util)).
But also consider append/2:

```
?- A=`ababab`.
A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98].

?- append([X,X,X],$A).
X = [97, 98],
A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98] ;
false.
```

Now, if we just find an easy way to make lists of repeated variables, we have a fairly powerful construct, we can use to tackle to problem. Let's try:

```
?- length(L,3),maplist(=(X),L).
L = [X, X, X].
```

So:

```
?- length(L,_),maplist(=(X),L),append(L,$A).
L = [[97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98]],
X = A, A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98] ;
L = [[97, 98], [97, 98], [97, 98]],
X = [97, 98],
A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98] ;
^CAction (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
```

oops, never ending story... but a bit boring. Need a bit more code, enforcing the domain knowledge (bagging, really...)

```
?- length($A,U),between(1,U,N),length(L,N),maplist(=(X),L),append(L,$A).
U = 6,
N = 1,
L = [[97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98]],
X = A, A = A, A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98] ;
U = 6,
N = 3,
L = [[97, 98], [97, 98], [97, 98]],
X = [97, 98],
A = A, A = [97, 98, 97, 98, 97, 98] ;
false.
```

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer :) 
This seems to only work for cases when there are only repetitions am I right ?
Let's say, I have A='mabcabc', how would I go about finding the same result as A='abcabc' ? Should I test all sub-strings ?

Comment: it's easy to insert skip lists in a fixed pattern, consider `?- append([_,X,X,X],$A).`, but it's not too easy to generalize... You should really try out the dcg_util pack, if you're running SWI. It's a bit steep to grasp, but **very** worth.

Comment: Oh ok, so if wanted to try to generalize this, I would be doing this in the maplist ?

Comment: Prolog is by heart a semantic grammar processor, running an important specification: Horn clauses first order logic. Well, to be practical programming tool it can exceed somewhere the pureness barrier...